# Add any missing rows and columns by matching to a key of all possible rows and columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am making tbls of the number of cases by year and age group for each county. Example df and vectors of all possible age groups, years, and counties:

```
    library(tidyverse)

    df <- data.frame(
      "year" = c(2010, 2010, 2011, 2013, 2014, 2014, 
                 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016),
      "age_group" = c("20-39", "0-19", "0-19", "60-79", 
                      "80-99", "20-39","20-39", "60-79", 
                      "20-39", "80-99"),
      "county" = c("a", "b", "b", "a", "c", "b", "b", 
                   "a", "a", "a")) 

    all_age_groups <- c("0-19", "20-39", "40-59", "60-79", "80-99")

    all_years <- c(2010:2017)

    all_counties <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

Counties "a", "b", and "c" are missing SOME age groups or years. County "d" is missing ALL age groups and years (no cases).

This works to add any missing age groups:

```
    ex_func <- function(df_orig, selectcounty) {
      df_age_group <- data.frame("age_group" = all_age_groups)
      df2 <- df_orig %>%
        filter(county == selectcounty) %>%
        group_by(age_group, year) %>%
        summarise(cases = n()) %>%
        spread(year, cases) %>%
        full_join(., df_age_group, by = "age_group") %>%
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        mutate(age_group = factor(age_group, levels = all_age_groups)) %>%
        arrange(age_group)
     df2
    }
```

But I haven't been able to successfully deal with the missing year columns without manually creating a new one for each missing year with `mutate`.

I am looking for a way, preferably in `dplyr`, to:

1) search for which years from `all_years` do not exist as columns in df

2) add columns for each year that is missing

3) make all rows for each new column equal to 0

4) maintain the order of the years (2010-2017) in the columns, and age groups in df$age_group

shorter version of desired outcome for county "b":

```
    df2 <- ex_func(df, "b")

    age_group `2010` `2011 `2012` `2013` `2014 `2015`   
    0-19         1     1     0      0      0     0
    20-39        0     0     0      0      1     1
    40-59        0     0     0      0      0     0
    60-79        0     0     0      0      0     0
    80-99        0     0     0      0      0     0
```

Comment: `?tidyr::complete`?

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% mutate(year=factor(year)) %>% group_by(year, age_group, county, .drop=FALSE) %>% tally`. `.drop=FALSE` keeps all combinations. This works only if all of the grouping variables are factor class, which is why I included code to convert year to a factor. The other columns are factor by default in your example. You'll need `dplyr` version 0.8 or higher.

Comment: Isn't it cool that eipi just helped e(i)pi_n00b?